# How to extract the date part from a timestamp field in apache drill?

Tags: sql, apache-drill, sql-date-functions

I have a timestamp field in a drill table (say date_time), How can I extract the date field only from the same. Saw lots of date operation functions [here](https://drill.apache.org/docs/date-time-functions-and-arithmetic/) but none of them helped.

Here is the sample data,

```
+------------------------+
|       date_time        |
+------------------------+
| 2017-01-01 03:45:58.0  |
| 2017-01-01 21:42:20.0  |
| 2017-01-01 15:08:47.0  |
| 2017-01-01 19:59:39.0  |
| 2017-01-01 22:37:24.0  |
+------------------------+
```

I need an output like follows,

```
+-------------+
|  date_time  |
+-------------+
| 2017-01-01  |
| 2017-01-01  |
| 2017-01-01  |
| 2017-01-01  |
| 2017-01-01  |
+-------------+
```

I don't want to do string operations. :)

Comment: `select cast(date_time as date) date_time from table ` this will bring the required output

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Comment: you can also use `select convert(varchar(10), current_timestamp,120)`

Comment: First one looks simple. I'm using this field for day wise grouping, so which of your option will be more efficient for a group by query.?

Comment: Simple casting (first one) would be efficient for grouping. But i can not think of differences between these 2. Anwyays, Check the performance using both in sample data

Comment: Sure, thanks for your support. :)

Comment: @Ven Could you please make your comment as an answer so that I can accept the  same, which may help other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this, if dates are properly formatted in your table. A simple method

```
select cast(date_time as date) date_time from table
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what is in the first comment--i.e., `cast(date_time as date)`--another option is:

```
select to_date(datetime)
```

The [Date/Time Functions page](https://drill.apache.org/docs/date-time-functions-and-arithmetic/) that you referenced should really have a link to https://drill.apache.org/docs/data-type-conversion/#other-data-type-conversions, which shows how to apply a custom format to a timestamp field:

```
select to_char(date_time, 'yyyyMMdd');
```